# How can I edit a DXF in node.js?

Tags: node.js, autocad, dxf

I'd like to make a custom lasered label from a user's input on a website. I have a template dxf file and I'd like to replace placeholder text with the user input. My problem is the dxf file format is very unreadable in its text format. Is there any way to make sense of the numeric data? If not are there any other formats (svg, etc) that would be easier to work with?

EDIT: The reason I've found it unreadable in terms of text is that the program (Solidworks) converted the text to curves.) At this point I'm trying to figure out how to prevent that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoDesk was nice enough to document DXF syntax in great detail. Spend a couple hours understanding the documentation from the link below, and I think you will find it quite easy to parse and edit using code.

To just replace some placeholder text, it should be just as simple as reading the DXF file into a string (a dxf file is no different than a txt file), performing a text replace operation and saving it back to file. Just make sure that your placeholder text is very unique and is not contained in any of the key words in the document below (otherwise your DXF file will get corrupted). Something like "PlaceHolderText" will do the trick.

http://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/autocad_2012_pdf_dxf-reference_enu.pdf

**Edit: More Info**

I do a lot of work with AutoDesk Inventor which is in direct competition with SolidWorks, so they are effectively the same tool. We were faced with a similar problem of needing to place text onto sheet metal flat pattern DXFs that came out of Inventor in order to identify the part, but Inventor simply could not do it (see, exactly the same!). One of our developers had the idea to place a very precise geometry punch onto the flat pattern. After the DXF was generated he wrote some code that parsed the DXF file and replaced the geometry with a text entity. More specifically we used a triangle with sides having each length defined to something like the 7th decimal place. You can then use one of the vertices of the triangle to position the text, including rotation. This process would be automatic, so once you write the code with the help of the document above (which won't take the long), it will just work. If your engraver can handle text the way you want it, I'd say this is a very good solution. We generate hundreds of parts every day using this code. Hope this helps.

Comment: I opened the dxf as a text file and there was just numbers. I did a search for the placeholder text (label 1) and it turned up no results.

Comment: Are you perhaps using a binary dxf?  In this case this would not work. You can tell if the format is binary by opening the file in NotePad. If the content looks like complete gibberish, its binary. If it looks like there is an order to it, its is ASCII. Could you confirm that you're using an ASCII or a binary dxf?

Comment: It is ASCII, there is definitely discernible data. I see all of the data for curves, lines and circles, but there is no text. I've tried searching both for the text itself and the keyword text, with no results

Comment: That doesn't seem right. 1) What software do you use to create and edit the dxf template? 2) How did you search for your placeholder text (i.e. match whole word, case sinsitive, etc)? Is your text perhaps MTEXT? Could you share your dxf file? I think it would be much easier to help you if I could examine it.

Comment: I didn’t make it, the engineers used autocad. A search for MTEXT also turned up empty. Unfortunately I’m not at liberty to share the file as these are company blueprints.

Comment: I’m wondering if autocad could have converteded the text to lines. There are thousands upon thousands of lines of text in this file that contains 24 circles, a rounded rectangle, and 12 labels. That just shouldn’t be that many lines.

Comment: It did indeed convert the text to curves

Comment: OK, you don't need to share your file, It all makes sense now! You probably have some very fancy text created via entities. Can you ask your engineers to use a text object with some fancy font rather than actually drawing it with entities? If they can do that for you, that will solve all your problems. If not, you'll have a tough time accomplishing your task regardless of the file type. That being said, it's still totally doable, but best talk to the engineers first to see if they can edit the template for you.

Comment: They are using a text object in a program called Solidworks. When this software exports to dxf for some reason it converts all the text to curves. They have no idea how to prevent that. :(

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have SolidWorks and I haven't used it in a couple years. It appears they have found a solution to this issue in this post: https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/185434. I can't verify it since I don't have SolidWorks, but your engineers should be able to make sense of it. If they still can't get it to work and this template almost never changes, you can always just add a text entity using NotePad rather than via SolidWorks. I can help you with that if needed.

Comment: I should also mention that if they can save it via AutoCAD, that will also work.

Comment: A workaround you can try if you have access to AutoCad: After exporting the DXF from SolidWorks, open it in AutoCad, delete the placeholder text and replace it with a text or mtext entity, and save it as a DXF. Now I am wondering, can your engraver/laser handle text? I would guess the placeholder text letters from SolidWorks likely have a thickness to it, and simple text does not. I know many devices can handle it, but something worth looking into before going down this path much further.

Comment: Manually calculating the position values for 48 labels and using textedit would be a huge pain. I don't know about the engraver handling text, but worst case scenario the conversion would be quick. At this point SVG seems to be the best scenario as I know I can work with the file. However, I also don't know how the engraver would handle SVG text.

Comment: I appreciate all your help with the DXF though. From your article it seems the engineers would need to do the text separate? I don't think that would work.

Comment: You're welcome. I added some more info to the answer you may find useful.